# problem in sending email with python smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtplib

When I enter my code as follows:

```
    import smtplib
    from email.message import EmailMessage
    fileMail=input("\nEnter the file : ")
    sub=input("\nEnter email subject : ")
    smtpServer=input("\nEnter smtp server addres : ")
    smtpPort=input("\nEnter smtp port number : ")
    myEmail=input("\n\nEnter your Email addres : ")
    myEmailPasswd=getpass()
    try:
        mailContent=input("\nEnter email content (Please enter the ^C to end) :")
        while 1:
            mailContent+="\n"+input(">")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n\n")

    # try :
    with open(fileMail,"r") as f:
        for emailAddr in f.readlines():
            # try:
            email = EmailMessage()
            email['from'] = myEmail
            email['to'] = emailAddr
            email['subject'] = sub
            email.set_content(mailContent)
            print(type(email['from']))
            with smtplib.SMTP(host=smtpServer, port=smtpPort) as smtp:
                smtp.ehlo()
                smtp.starttls()
                smtp.login(myEmail, myEmailPasswd)
                smtp.send_message(email)
                print(f'\n[✔️]Email was sent => {color.LIGHTRED_EX}{emailAddr}{randomColor()}')
```

The email is sent as follows: ‌
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRrqS.png)

But when my code is as follows:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage()
email['from'] = 'f@gmail.com'
email['to'] = 'f2@gmail.com'
email['subject'] = 'None'
print(type(email['subject']))
email.set_content('This is the content of my email')
with smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login('f@gmail.com', 'pass')
    smtp.send_message(email)
    print('email was sent!')
```

The email will be sent as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00RTl.png)

I mean, when I enter the email values manually in the code, all the sections are displayed correctly in the email client, but when I receive these values as a input, sections like (sender subject or ...) Email is not displayed correctly

Comment: You shouldn't see those headers.  The mail reader app will use them to format your display, but they aren't part of the message.  Is it possible you selected "show headers" in your second example?

Comment: If you get carefully to both code you'll find no difference

Comment: I wasn't asking about the code.  I was asking about your mail reader.  Is it possible you had "show headers" turned on when you looked at the second message?